# Where is the flag count displayed on Stack Overflow profile?

Tags: support, flag-history

Where in my Stack Overflow profile can I see the flags that I have raised? The flags raised are not shown under the activity tab.

Edit: I can see the flag count, but not the posts that I have flagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the profile view count you will find the link `[helpful flags  xxx]`.
Just click on count and you will be redirected to each flagged post list.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1294802

Comment: thanks for the answer.. +1, will have to wait to mark it as accepted though. :)